# Lock-free buffer

Tags: c, thread-safety, locking, buffer, c99

In my code I have a buffer, and my code to add data to it is:

```
bool push_string(file_buffer *cb, const char* message, const unsigned short msglen)
{
    unsigned int size = msglen;

    if(cb->head >= (cb->size - size))
    {
        size = cb->size - cb->head - 1;
    }

    if(size < 1) return false;

    char* dest = cb->head += size;

    memcpy(dest, message, size);

    return (size == msglen);
}
```

Since I add data from multiple interrupts (which can exempt eachother), I was wondering if this code is thread-safe? I marked 'cb->head' as volatile, but if another interrupt exempts exactly between the increase of 'head' and the asignment to 'dest', things could go wrong.

How can I improve this code to make it safer?

EDIT: Maybe I shouldn't have used the term 'thread-safe' because there are no threads running in parallel, just the possibility of interrupts.

Comment: No... definitely not threadsafe, as there's no synchronisation mechanisms at all. Getting lock-free algorithms robustly implemented is difficult - if you have to ask if the above is safe, you should start with a mutex.  The data structure above is not even capable of being populated in a lock-free manner, as you're writing arbitrarily large messages in and the reader has no way to know when they're safe to consume.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. It's not as simple as using a spinlock. The problem is, if one ISR acquires the spinlock and then gets interrupted/preempted by another ISR, that other ISR won't be able to acquire the spinlock. If it does, the system will deadlock.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: how's that supposed to help? Most mutex implementations spin before falling back on a more CPU-friendly OS-level lock. Simply spinning in user code risks wasting huge numbers of CPU cycles.  As for deadlocks - whether that can happen depends on whether the interrupts can preempt each other or always run to completion.

Comment: @TonyD If you move small amounts of data under a spinlock and not that frequently, spinning doesn't become a problem, but can guarantee exclusive access to the shared object (buffer).

Comment: (By way of contrast) for lock-free operation, you generally use a two-phase approach - updating data somewhere then compare-and-swapping in/out the links thereto.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: lock-free algorithms are about spinning on the data itself - not a separate lock.  "spinning doesn't become a problem" - you can still acquire the lock, yield, and leave other threads burning their entire timeslice, and for what when a mutex spins first anyway?  And who wants an approach to locking that becomes exponentially worse as the frequency of locking increases?

Comment: @TonyD I think we're starting to speculate. We probably need more data to make a definitive suggestion.

Comment: It's running on a Cortex M0 CPU with very primitive C-environment, so I have no spinlocks/mutexes/etc available (or I would have to implement the code for them myself). I dont care if there is a small chance that data gets overwritten by another interrupt, I just want to make sure it will never write outside the boundaries of the memory allocated for the buffer.

Comment: @Joshua: you can't be sure it'll write inside the buffer: `cb->head` could be bounds-checked in one interrupt handler, then `cb->head += size` moves it along in a second handler, then execution returns to the first and writes too much at the new `cb->head`.

Comment: @TonyD So is there a design possible (without mutexes/locks) that would be safe? Or is this problem inherently unsolvable?

Comment: @Joshua: I think it must be possible, even though I don't know that specific CPU or _how_ it supports memory synchronisation, atomic operations etc..  I think the cleanest approach is to see if you can disable preemption by further interrupts for long enough to lay claim to the block of memory you're going to write to and update `cb->head`... there's probably a simple way to do that.

Comment: On my embedded systems, I have disabled interrupt preemption,(except for FIQ), for precisely this reason - to enable buffer pointers to be pushed/popped to/from queues without interference from other interrupts.  Each interrupt handler is short enough for me to achieve sufficient performance.  The FIQ can interrupt another interrupt but can only signal completion of its SD-card read/write by initiating an 'ordinary' software interrupt, so it's buffer queue is protected in a similar manner.  Mutex are not available in interrupt handlers, even if you had an RTOS.

Answer (score 0):

C99 has no concept of threads and thus none for thread-savety either. Only C11 has.
In C99 the only data type that is interrupt safe is `sig_atomic_t`, but evidently this says nothing about threads either.

Generally you are completely mistaken in attempting to access data structures concurrently, `volatile` is no guarantee at all that you receive sensible data. There is no guarantee as such of atomicity of any of the operations, even in C11, so you could e.g be in a situation where the lower half of a pointer value is already written but not the upper half. This could give you a completely bogus result. Since such thing would perhaps just happen once in a million or under special circumstances (heavy load e.g) this could lead to bugs that are very difficult to trace.

Don't do that.

C11 gives you new tools to handle such things, in particular atomic operations. It is not completely implemented but many compilers already have extensions that could help you. I have wrapped some of these in the [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) macro package, so with certain compilers you could start to use these features as of today.

Comment: The coded is running on an embedded sytem (Cortex M0), so I'm afraid I cannot use C11 in my dev environment, but I will look into it.

Comment: There is no reason why you shouldn't. In particular the part on atomic operations should work. Cortex is from the ARM family isn't it? P99 has atomic support for that processor.

Comment: Cortex M0 has no atomic operation support in the instruction set. Cortex M3 is the first that has it. P99 uses the atomic instructions to implement the atomic operations and will not work on Cortex M0.

Answer (score 0):

Think about signals interrupting signals... if you really need that:

You could block all relevant signals while in push_string().

Another, application dependant possibility might be moving the signal handler code into the main 'thread' (signal handler code just generate 'events' that wake up the main thread of execution). I have not enough information about your app, to say if it is a good choice or not.

Comment: In my main thread I read out this buffer and write it to SDCard, but mulitple interrupts need to be able to fill this buffer. Im thinking about giving each interrupt a different buffer, and combine them in Main(), but it would require a lot of extra RAM and makes things more complex. I hoped there was a simple way to make this interrupt-safe.

Comment: I'm not at all sure that there is, apart from disabling interrupt-preemption while twiddling queue indexes/pointers.  As you say, giving each interrupt its own set of buffers and a separate queue is wasteful of RAM, which is always too small on these embedded jobs anyway :((